# Prompt for Second Factor Notification Only

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

I'm creating an application backed by Azure AD with MFA required (via Conditional Access Policies). After a user logs into (using the msal library)  into the application, is there a way to just trigger a notification on my second factor (Authenticator app or SMS) when a user performs certain actions. Say I want to re-confirm the user before they are allow to transfer money but I don't want them to have to re-login, just prompt on their authenticator app.

I looked at doing something like

```
authResult = await app.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault(), UIBehavior.Never, "amr=ngcmfa");
```

But this does not trigger the second factor, just refreshes the access tokens.

Is this possible today with msal?

Answer (score 0):

The right way of doing is not programmatically in your app, but through the Azure portal. you (or the tenant admin) need to add a conditional access policy in Azure AD for the application, requiring users to have MFA. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview